# Closed form of Eulerian numbers Proof

Tags: combinatorics, eulerian-numbers

I was reading the proof of the closed-form formula of Eulerian numbers ($A(n,k)$) from Bona's book. I had a doubt in his classification of "removable fences" and how they eliminate the undesirable permutations. [image: Basic setup described in the book]

When we are counting the total number of desired permutations, we see that 2 things might happen which lead to undesirable permutations (| is a fence and signifies the separation of the compartments/concessions):

- Empty compartments/concessions (eg: 234||1)
- Neighboring compartments/concessions with no descent in between (eg: 12|3)

Bona classifies a fence $f$ as **removable** if it satisfies these 2 conditions:

1. If we remove $f$, we still have a permutation whose entries increase
   between any two consecutive fences, and
2. the fence $f$ is not immediately followed by another fence

He then says that any permutation that doesn't contain any removable fence has $k$ ascending runs. I do not understand why this definition of removable works (if possible, please explain through examples) and why this eliminates undesirable permutations. For instance, say we are counting $A(6,3)$, it still counts permutations of type 124||356, which isn't a desirable permutation as it only has 2 ascending runs.

Comment: In 124||356, the first fence is removable since it is immediately followed by another fence, so this would not be counted.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, I don't think that is true as a fence is removable if it **isn't** immediately followed by another fence.

Comment: I made a mistake; however, the _second_ fence is removable, so it is still not counted. Essentially, if there are multiple fences in a row, Bona will only count the rightmost one as removable, probably to make counting easier somehow.

Comment: @MikeEarnest That makes sense. I am still confused about how this handles all the bad permutations though. I think my confusion now is arising because of the first condition of removable fence.